# Laravel 5 Eloquent where clause

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

how can I operate on the where clause?
For example I have this query

```
 Product::where('purchase_data', '=', $data_inp)->get();
```

The problem is that I need to operate a formatting on the content of column purchase_data before is compared. What can i do?

Edit to be more specific
The column purchase_data has date values formatted in a certain way, the $data_inp variable is also a date but with another formatting. In order to compare them they have to use the same format; since I can't format the $data_inp variable to the same format of the content of purchase_data, I need to change the format of the content of the purchased_data column before comparing it with the $data_inp variable

Comment: can you be more precise on your question?

Comment: yes, sorry.   The column purchase_data has date values formatted in a certain way, the $data_inp variable is also a date but with another formatting. In order to compare them they have to use the same format; since I can't format the $data_inp variable to the same format of the content of purchase_data, I need to change the format of the content of the purchased_data column before comparing it with the $data_inp variable

Answer (score 0):

Try using `whereRaw` 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions
Then you can transform the column to compare.

Comment: Can you add a very basic example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 Product::whereRaw('purchase_data = '.$data_inp)->get();
```

Then format the `purchase_data` to your need

Read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions)